# How to use storage FUSE in google cloud run?

Tags: google-cloud-run

How to use storage FUSE in google cloud run ? I saw the examples with Google App Engine, etc. How to use it in google cloud run?

Comment: What have you tried? What results did you get? What errors or problems? Cloud Run is serverless containers. However, one of the issues is that in between HTTP requests the CPU is idled to zero which means that socket connections will fail. Cloud Run is in beta, try it with FUSE and let us know what you discover.

Answer (score 2):

It is not yet possible to use FUSE on Google Cloud Run. I recommend using the Google Cloud Storage client libraries to read and write files to Cloud Storage

Answer (score 0):

It seems that now we can use Cloud Storage FUSE from Cloud Run, see [official tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/network-filesystems-fuse).

This a high level of the needed steps:

- Create a `Dockerfile` for your application by copying [gcsfuse.Dockerfile](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/run/filesystem/gcsfuse.Dockerfile)
- Modifying the startup script [gcsfuse_run.sh](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/run/filesystem/gcsfuse_run.sh) to start your application, in the example they started a gunicorn webserver.